# Select entities lacking a property, or with a property value below some limit

Tags: sparql, graphdb

> I want to start a club.  You can't join if there's evidence that your age is 48 or greater.

**Data:**

```
@prefix ns0: <http://example.com/> .

ns0:Mark 
  a ns0:person ;
  ns0:age 48 .

ns0:Anne
  a ns0:person ;
  ns0:age 41 .

ns0:Steven a ns0:person .
```

**Query 1:**

```
prefix ns0: <http://example.com/> 
select ?s
where {
    ?s   a ns0:person ;
         ns0:age ?age .
    filter (?age < 48)
}
```

*Result 1:  ns0:Anne*

**Query 2:**

```
prefix ns0: <http://example.com/> 
select ?s
where {
    ?s   a ns0:person .
    minus {
        ?s ns0:age ?age .
    }
}
```

*Result 2:  ns0:Steven*

**Query 3:**

```
prefix ns0: <http://example.com/> 
select ?s
where {
    {
        ?s   a ns0:person .
        minus {
            ?s ns0:age ?age .
        } 
    }
    union {
        ?s   a ns0:person ;
             ns0:age ?age .
        filter (?age < 48)
    }
}
```

*Result 3:  GraphDB 8.6.0 returns two rows, but doesn't name Anne and Mark:*

```
|   | s        |
|---|----------|
| 1 |          |
| 2 | ns0:Anne |
```

Comment: It's mostly likely a bug in GraphDB. At least, it works with Apache Jena as expected. Did you try `filter not exists{?s ns0:age ?age }` as an alternative to the `minus` clause?

Comment: Another alternative is: `prefix ns0: <http://example.com/>
select ?s
where {
        ?s   a ns0:person
             OPTIONAL {?s ns0:age ?age}
        filter (!bound(?age) || ?age < 48)
}`

Comment: Thanks.  Both the `filter( X || Y)` and `filter not exists` forms do work in GraphDB 8.6.0.  My Query 3 doesn't work in the latest GraphDB (8.8.1), either.

Comment: Ok. It's a strange bug, probably somewhere in the combination of `union` and `minus` given that both queries work but just the union does not. You should contact the devs. They know better than me.

Comment: By the way, in your question you say *"Result 3: GraphDB 8.6.0 returns two rows, but doesn't name Anne and Mark:"* but I guess you meant *"...Anne and Steven"* ?

Comment: Just to confirm that it is indeed a bug in GraphDB when evaluating MINUS within UNION.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Damyan Ognyanov response, the bug will be fixed in the upcoming 8.9 release.